# Can HAML do a "capture", kind of like a render_to_string in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I heard that HAML has a `capture` function that can do something like Ruby on Rails's `render_to_string`, but can't find info on it.  Actually, in View, we can use  `aString = render :partial ...` and `render` actually works the same as `render_to_string` (as on Rail 2.2.2).  But is there also an HAML way of doing it by `capture`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can capture the Haml buffer with [capture_haml](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method). You have to `include Haml::Helpers` in order to use it.

However, I am not sure if it works for capturing partials. From my understanding, I'd say that Haml is independent from render and thus, render_to_string or render :partial should also work for Haml.

At least, the following will work:

```
str = capture_haml do
  haml_tag "p#feedback.success", "Your request has been successful."
end

str # => "<p id='feedback' class='success'>Your request has been successful.</p>"
```